# How to tell tlmgr not to pull from a specific mirror?

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

My texlive is set up to pull updates from any nearby mirror. The issue is that one specific mirror consistently produces errors when updating that cause packages to be forcibly removed. For example, running `tlmgr update --all` this morning produced in the terminal

```
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://us.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/backups
[1/8, ??:??/??:??] update: expex-glossonly [72k] (67958 -> 68860) ... TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\mbert\AppData\Local\Temp\EHiPH5r8Jo\yvAXANUM6s/expex-glossonly.doc.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=094f2c57bbd2a85771d7c4993174a292dd15733e735ffeecedca64d5f737be537c96b00c2c41243364baed17d41fc62706e100ccf4f71f6c8f289ab803495aa7, arg=7ff5b9dfada3ef37c0ddc28a472a33a816d52b7b9b265291c640527e6b8974ca21d5867f7e271856a920589062eab5563b29c919a7df66b51af93af5e12fed5c
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2650: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1985: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1856: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1736: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:3380: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:798: main::action_update
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:704: main::execute_action
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:367: main::main
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\mbert\AppData\Local\Temp\EHiPH5r8Jo\yvAXANUM6s/expex-glossonly.doc.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\mbert\AppData\Local\Temp\U_VkBCQQDZ
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for https://us.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/expex-glossonly.doc.tar.xz
tlmgr.pl: Installation of new version of expex-glossonly failed, trying to unwind.
Cannot open tlpobj file: C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/tlpobj/expex-glossonly.tlpobj at C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 72.
```

The problematic mirror is `https://us.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet`. Without specifying a specific mirror to always pull from, is it possible to configure texlive to never pull from that specific mirror? I couldn't find anything about this in the [texlive documentation](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html). Right now all I can do is run `tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed` and hope for a different mirror.

Answer (score 1):

I have had multiple issues recently with the `cicku.me` mirror too.

AFAIK, you can't exclude a specific mirror from the [Mirror Multiplexor](https://www.ctan.org/mirrors) service run by CTAN. You can only avoid using it and instead specify a specific mirror to use (only), e.g. use only the mirror of Princeton University with:

```
sudo tlmgr option repository https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/
```